# porque cuando uso sublimetext quiero usar el color de CSS pero no me hace nada? en cambio si pongo la etiqueta style en html si funciona

Tags: html, css, color, style

[image: ese es en HTML pero en CSS no funciona ni con Style ni con color, etc.]
CSS:
h1 color: orange; en css no hace nada pero si pongo style, el color, etc. si funiona en HTML si

```
                </style>
```

Comment: Será por el orden en que se procesan los estilos. Lo llaman **Especificidad**. Encontrarás más info en [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Seguramente unos estilos estan machacando a otros en tu caso.

Comment: Será porque no enlazas correctamente tu archivo css con tu html. Aprovecho este comentario para decirte que tu pregunta no se entiende apenas, y que el códgio tiene que estar en formato texto en vez de con una imágen. Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y la formules de mejor manera.